# Probability of exact number of free throws before failing a set amount of times

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

Two people started shooting free throws simultaneously. One is able to hit the basket $67\%$ of the time, the other can score $78\%$ of their shots. Their shots are paired. They keep shooting until the number of unsuccessful pairs reaches $6$.

1. What is the probability that exactly 9 pairs of shots will be taken if we consider either or both players missing their shot an unsuccessful pair [a pair is successful only if they both hit their shot]?

The probability of them both hitting the basket in a pair is $$0.67 * 0.78 = 0.5226 $$

The probability of an opposite event (an unsuccessful pair) is $$1 - 0.67 * 0.78 = 0.4774$$

If they are bound to shoot exactly 9 pairs of shots, they must get $3$ successful pairs, $6$ unsuccessful pairs, and the $9$th pair must be unsuccessful.

For any of the other $8$ pairs of shots their order can be chosen freely.

From this we get

$$C(8, 5) * 0.4774^6 * 0.5226^3 ≈ 0.0946 $$

The probability is approximately $0.0946$.

2. What is the probability that exactly 9 pairs of shots will be taken if we consider exactly one of the players missing an unsuccessful pair [if both hit or miss - that's called a successful pair]?

A successful pair occurs if they both miss or score, the probability of a successful pairs then is $$0.67 * 0. 78 + (1-0.67)*(1-0.78) = 0.5952$$

The probability of an unsuccessful pair is $$1-0.5952 = 0.4048$$

Once again, if they are bound to shoot exactly 9 pairs of shots, they must get 3 successful pairs, 6 unsuccessful pairs, and the 9th pair must be unsuccessful. For any of the other 8 pairs of shots their order can be chosen freely.

From this we get

$$C(8, 5) * 0.4048^6 * 0.5952^3 ≈ 0.05195 $$

The probability is approximately $0.05195$.

Is all of this correct?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: I haven't checked your calculations, but your strategy is correct for both parts of the problem.